# C++ 2D algorithm code is reading the array wrong

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

Like the title said, my code is reading a 2D array entirely wrong.

```
    const int WINNING_ROWS[8][3] = { (0, 1, 2),
                                     (3, 4, 5),
                                     (6, 7, 8),
                                     (0, 3, 6),
                                     (1, 4, 7),
                                     (2, 5, 8),
                                     (0, 4, 8),
                                     (2, 4, 6) };
```

Above is my 2D array of numbers.
My program doesn't seem to be able to read it properly.

For example, if I were to ask for row 2, item 1, I would expect 7, it, however, instead gives me 6.
Here is a list of rows and item requests I have done to try and figure out what has gone wrong here.

- row 0, item 0, expected outcome 0, actual outcome 2
- row 3, item 2, expected outcome 6, actual outcome 0
- row 1, item 0, expected outcome 3, actual outcome 6
- row 5, item 1, expected outcome 5, actual outcome 0
- **row 8, item 2, expected outcome 6, actual outcome 13629648**
- row 7, item 2, expected outcome 6, actual outcome 0

for reference, here is the code I have been using to call the items from the array

```
cout << WINNING_ROWS[7][2] << endl;
```

**Edit 1: ignore the item in bold, that was a mistake on my part when testing my code.**

**Edit 2: my question has been answered.**

Comment: `WINNING_ROWS[8][2]` is outside of the bounds of the array. You are reading the 9th line of a matrix with 8 lines.

Comment: Your ( ) are your problem. Use {} instead of () here: [https://ideone.com/LSofPh](https://ideone.com/LSofPh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const int WINNING_ROWS[8][3] = { (0, 1, 2),
                                     (3, 4, 5),
                                     (6, 7, 8),
                                     (0, 3, 6),
                                     (1, 4, 7),
                                     (2, 5, 8),
                                     (0, 4, 8),
                                     (2, 4, 6) };
```

That doesn't mean what you think it does.  The `(0,1,2)` is **not** a row of three elements, but a single integer computed using the comma operator.  `0,1,2` evaluates to `2`.

You need to use the proper `{...}` braces instead of parenthesis, or leave them out completely.

---

Suggest also you change `const` to `constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you, *so much*. I would never have been able to catch that on my own.

Comment: Those can be the hardest things to find!

Answer (score 1):

`WINNING_ROWS[8][2]` is out of the array bounds, which means it will cause undefined behavior. If you want to get the last element, you should try `cout << WINNING_ROWS[7][2] << endl;` since they are 0-indexed.

Comment: thank you for that, I forgot to count from 0 for that half of calling the array in that instance, however the prevailing issue is still there, the rest of my code doesn't seem to be reading the array right.